# What are the limitations of Selenium

Tags: selenium

Could you please let me know the limitations od Selenium IDE, Selenium RC, Selenium GRID
Thanks all for the help

Answer (score 5):

You can't interact with flash elements and java applets

Answer (score 5):

Don't expect Selenium to work as you expect it to 100% of the time. For instance, sometimes it doesn't know when the page has finished loading (because of AJAX running in the background).

Other limitations:
1) It can't use a proxy to connect to any website
That's because Selenium, technically is already a proxy, and you can't really configure it to go through another proxy (at least not that I know of)

2) Buggy with IE, Opera, and even Google Chrome
For the most part, most of the functionality interacting with the GUI will work in Firefox. Not so much with the other browsers.

Comment: For AJAX loading you can try waitForCondition api to wait for element to be available on page before you proceed further.

Answer (score 5):

One argument which I often here against Selenium is, it is only for web applications and can not be used for desktop application.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Selenium-rc without a web-driver, and I see the following problem: 
very difficult with cross-browser, if you write tests for firefox, not the fact what that they will work in MS-IE or chrome. I think that Selenium two chose the wrong way, if each browser has its own implementation of the driver, I think will be compatibility problems.

Answer (score 2):

Selenium doesn't have an integrated spreadsheet for data driven testing (parameterization), always need to use external files for it.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium IDE does not allow for conditional statements, loops, assserting HTML. Selenium RC has problems with modal dialogs, yet there are hacks, it's not completely flexible for it.  I'm also noticing that RC tests are not completely compatible with Selenium 2 using the python driver.  Also agree with [@Rusty Robot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308973/what-are-the-limitations-of-selenium/5315426#5315426) that not all tests are guaranteed compatible across browsers.  With all that being said, I think Selenium will be around for a while as there is a lot of investment from Google.  I remember seeing some number that throughout Google they have over 51K test scripts and an entire Server farm to run their tests.  Just like any automated framework, there will be overhead and costs for maintenance, but overall I'm enjoying my experience with it.